# how to NOT search active record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am new to RoR. I met one question which is: some active records may not needed to be searched for in database(let's say they are expired). I don't want to delete it from database because it is associated with other models. Also since it is expired, I don't want it to be updated. Is there any way to handle this situation in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways. But I recommend you to use https://github.com/radar/paranoia

You can find a good screencast here: https://gorails.com/episodes/soft-delete-with-paranoia

It is really easy to add to your app. Just add the gem to your Gemfile and add `acts_as_paranoid` to your model.

Comment: Thanks Bjoernsen. The cast you recommended is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A Rails plugin to add soft delete.

This gem can be used to hide records instead of deleting them, making them recoverable later.

https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid

Comment: Thanks very much. This gem also recommended by Bjoernsen.

Answer (score 0):

Your question(s)

1. **Avoid querying a subset of your data:**
   *For this one ought to utilize ActiveRecord's scopes. Specifically use a default scope. Ref here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html. Incidentally, this is the mechanism that the soft-delete gems I have come across utilize to hide soft-delete records
2. **How to prevent updating the records:**
   *Not sure how you mean. What about the records that you are not going to be using will be (automatically?) updated?*

Comment: Thanks Seartles. Seems soft-delete is the method I am looking for. Will try to add the gem in my app. As for question 2, now I can still use update (/edit) method to change the database even though it is expired. There might be difference if using paranoia gem. I will give it a try first.

Comment: Consider using "kakurenbo-puti" instead of Paranoia's. The former does not override ActiveRecord methods. That gives you a lot more flexibility.